# Feature selection by overfitting a small sample size

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, feature-selection, convolutional-neural-network

I am using a CNN based model to do sequence classification. Since training an entire dataset is very expensive, and I have a large set of features needed to try, its impossible for me to select features by full trainings.

Usually a good sanity check before training, is try to let model overfit a small set of training samples, to make sure the model is at least capable of remember a small sample size.

Borrowed from this idea, my question is, can I train a small subset of training data, and use its loss curve as a metric, to select best features? Each training is to test how quick would the training loss converges given a subset of selected features.

Comment: Regarding the details of our problem, I didn't understand few points. Your input is a sequence. Are you using RNN or CNN? Besides, how do you extract the features from the sequence? If the input to your algorithm is a fixed set of feature, having a sequence as their source is not an important issue.

Comment: I am actually using CNN to do stock market prediction, the input is a sequence of  market behavior, features are extracted using varies methods, price differences, trading volume, indicators etc..

Comment: And how do you get from the sequence to the features? Do you use the convolutions for feature extraction or another layer?

Comment: No, its all hand crafted features, hopping it can ease the training.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Congratulations! You have suggested independently the [Wrapper method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection#Wrapper_method) for feature selection. Yes, you can use this method. 
However, consider that the wrapper method is slow since you have to train a model for each iteration. More than that, feature selection is a NP-complete problem so don't expect the optimal subset.